# Laravel 5.1 use count,sum, group by having or having

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, query-builder

Please help , how can I transfer those code to query builder?

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(used_count),COUNT(code)
FROM promo_codes pc 
LEFT JOIN promo_code_user pcu on pc.id=pcu.`promo_code_id` 
LEFT JOIN promo_code_types pct on pc.`promo_code_type_id`=pct.id 
WHERE (pc.expiry_date >= CURDATE() or pc.expiry_date is NULL) and
      (pct.expiry_date >= CURDATE() or pct.expiry_date is null) 
GROUP BY code
HAVING ( (sum(used_count) < global_max_uses  or sum(used_count) is null) and
       ( count(code) < max_users  or count(code) is null) ) ;
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test the query so i tried something on the fly.

```
$promo = DB::table('promo_codes')
    ->select(‘*’,DB::raw('SUM(used_count),COUNT(code)'))
    ->leftjoin('promo_code_user','promo_codes.id','=','promo_code_user.promo_code_id')
    ->leftjoin('promo_code_types','promo_codes.promo_code_type_id','=','promo_code_types.id')
    ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('promo_codes. expiry_date', '>=',DB::raw('curdate()'))
                  ->orWhereNull('promo_codes.expiry_date');
        })
    ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('promo_code_types.expiry_date', '>=', DB::raw('curdate()'))
                  ->orWhereNull('promo_code_types.expiry_date');
        })
    ->groupBy('code')
    ->havingRaw((sum(used_count) < global_max_uses  or sum(used_count) is null) and
   ( count(code) < max_users  or count(code) is null)
)->get();
```

If you find any errors post them here in order to help you

Comment: Be careful, you are using both ’ and ' character, what will end on errors.

Comment: I replaced them

Comment: It works fine, But I cause the other problem, I can't use paginate with havingRaw here

Comment: if you replace get() with paginate() which is the error message?

Comment: yes, I just checked from stackoverflow know that can not use paginate with having querry, just fixed. thank you